# Filling a character array with subsequent letters in a string

Tags: java

For example I need to get the string "Example" split by characters and fill a character array with a determined size and then stop when the array is full.

So if the character array had 10 elements then the resulting array would have components:

```
{E,x,a,m,p,l,e,E,x,a}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the chars to the array in a loop. You can use the original string's length to put in the fitting char using `charAt(i % a.length())`.

```
String a = "Example";
char[] b = new char[10];
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = a.charAt(i % a.length());
}
for (char x : b) System.out.println(x);
```